# conversion from Date ojbect to Date object

Tags: java, date

I have a requirement. I want to convert Date object to formatted Date object.

I mean,

```
`Date d = new Date();System.out.println(d);'
```

**Output:**  Thu Apr 05 11:28:32 GMT+05:30 2012

I want output to be like **05/APR/2012**. And the output object must be Date and not String.
If at all you are not clear , I'll post more clearly

Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Month : If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number. So i dont think `05/APR/2012` will be a date, it will be a string only

Comment: 05/APR/2012 is always a String representation of your `Date()`, so use appropriate`DateFormat`

Comment: -1 This question does not make sense. OP wants to output date as date object and not a string object. But actually every non-primitive type is converted to string before outputting.

Comment: @Vipul you mentioned elsewhere on this page that you have to set Date type field of a pojo, in that case : Edit your question and include complete problem description. Also mention which tool you are using to generate POJOs for database object or if you are generating them manually. Also tell which database are you using.

Comment: @Vipul did you check my answer? Did that help? Actually when POJOs or anything is inserted to database, all their values are converted to strings. Database does not have anything to do with Data types of a programming language. Please try to get that.

Answer (score 7):

Don't need any third party APIs, just use [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse/format Dates by providing date format pattern. The sample code would be:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(date);

System.out.println(formattedDate.toUpperCase());
```

[Demo run here.](http://ideone.com/kYd9Z)

Comment: @Vipul WTH you want that outputted object is date? Since every non-primitive type object will be converted to string by out.print methods

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use this format for formatting (outputting Date as String) and parsing (retrieving Date from String). Using this you can achieve back-end-to-front-end and visa verse communication.

Everything that you see on the user interface is output using Object's toString() method representation by default.

Basically formattedDate.toUpperCase() here prints to System.out OutputStream invoking toString() on formattedDate.toUpperCase().

Comment: i dont want output on the console..I had to set it to a Pojo object having Date field.. and i had to insert it into database..

Comment: @Vipul Edit your question and include complete problem description. Also mention which tool you are using to generate POJOs for database object or if you are generating them manually. Also tell which database are you using.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, I will let others know that OP is actually using POJOs for representing Database objects, one of his POJO contains Date type field. And he wants the date to be in oracles format, yet it remains Date object. (From OP's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023423/conversion-from-date-ojbect-to-date-object/10023686#comment12819321_10023686))

You just need to extend `Date` Class and override `public String toString();`

```
public class MyDate extends Date
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(this);
        return formattedDate;
    }
}
```

And then, in your POJO, where you initialize your Date object:

```
Date databaseDate=new MyDate();
// initialize date to required value.
```

Now databaseDate is a Date object, yet it will give your required format where it needs.

**EDIT:** Database does not have anything to do with Data types of a programming language. When POJOs are inserted to database, all their values are converted to strings. And how an object is converted to string is defined in toString method of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to use a Date in System.out.println() so we can try extending the Date class and overriding toString().

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Date;


 class date extends Date {

    int mm,dd,yy;
    date()
    {

        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d);
        mm=d.getMonth();
        dd=d.getDate();
        yy=d.getYear();

    }

    public String toString()
    {  Integer m2=new Integer(mm);
    Integer m3=new Integer(dd);
    Integer m4=new Integer(yy);
        String s=m2.toString() + "/"+ m3.toString() + "/" + m4.toString();

        return s;
    }


}

public class mai
{
public static void main(String... args)
{

    date d=new date();
    System.out.println(d);

}

}
```

Comment: The Date output i had to insert into database. 

i have to set the formateed Date ouptut to a Pojo object which has date of birth field of type Date and insert into database. 

i can set it to String. But the pojo has dependencies problem..

Comment: @Vipul then Edit your question and include complete problem description. Also mention which tool you are using to generate POJOs for database object or if you are generating them manually. Also tell which database are you using.

Comment: I am using oracle database. Iam writing manually hbm files and pojo classes.. i have to set the current date into the database.so iam creating a Date object. but that date is not in the dd/MMM/yyyy format.    I want date to be in dd/MMM/yyyy format inserted into the database.Please help..thanks

Comment: why would you want to force that on the database??Better handled separately.